# Python ODEINT is passed non-zero y'' but returns zero y' and y

Tags: python

I am attempting to build a balloon with hanging payload balloon dynamics simulator in Python. I solved the problem by hand first and now am attempting to implement it. I have created a function which serves as my dynamics simulator with three degrees of freedom. When I pass it my initial conditions,

```
u = [0]*6
t = 0
```

it returns a non-zero value for all of my second order derivatives. However, when it is plugged into odeint, the third DOF is shown to be zero for all t. However, based on the dynamic simulation for the initial conditions above, the third DOF should experience some change. What is causing this incongruity?

Comment: Show us the code. Just telling us the symptoms of a problem rarely lets us determine what the cause is.